# Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory

Tags: yaml, swagger, response, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Im trying swagger mule and wrote one different flow .
after starting run mule application, once deployment is done,

When i hit http://:port/swagger.json
i get this response " Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory "

Comment: i have jackson.daatafomat jar build

Comment: Please post your code so that others can help debug it.